# Query regarding JNI Implementation

Tags: java-native-interface

We have a service in Java which use JNI to invoke a method written in C++. I have few questions on how the method in C++ is invoked.
1) Can anyone describe briefly on how the JNI architecture works(Thing i am looking in particular are What happens when C++ method is called? Who will execute the method? What happens after the method returns? Who will allocate the memory to the method? Where will the memory gets allotted? How is the allotted memory released from RAM, Who will release the memory, When will the memory gets released)

Comment: Read the JNI Specification or the book. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple description, take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

If you are looking for more detailed description, take a look here:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javatm-native-interface/0201325772/

If you are looking for more technical details, check the specification here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

Have fun with JNI!